# Get row from indexPath in RoboVM

Tags: objective-c, nsindexpath, robovm

I am trying to write the following objective-c code in robovm:

```
   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath = ...;
   cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

However, when I look thru RoboVM's calls for NSIndexPath here:
 
https://github.com/robovm/robovm/blob/e60579613140f4a6d48f108042633fbf17b9c289/cocoatouch/src/main/java/org/robovm/apple/foundation/NSIndexPath.java

or by scrolling thru Eclipse's options, I don't see anything corresponding to row. What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with RoboVM. However, `indexPath.section` and `indexPath.row` are just convenience methods/properties for

```
[indexPath indexAtPosition:0] // section
[indexPath indexAtPosition:1] // row
```

and the `indexAtPosition:` method *is* defined in the Java class.

Comment: Thanks! I had tried this, but didn't realize position 0 was section instead of row, so I thought it didn't work, since I only have one section. Thanks for clearing that up.